# Room Migration - Change INTEGER column type to nullable (SQLLITE)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a version 1 database with an int column.
In version 2, I want to make my column nullable, to achieve this I have changed my column data type to Integer from int in my java entity class.

Since after some research I realized it's not possible to change just the data type of a column.

Here what I am doing in my migration method:

My original entity name is TaskEntity, I am creating a new temp table, copying the data and then dropping the original table and then renaming the temp table to original table.

```
        database.execSQL(
                "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" +

                "CREATE TABLE TaskEntityNew('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                        "'text' TEXT," +
                        "'caseid' INTEGER NULL," +
                        "'status' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
                        "'datetime' DATETIME," +
                        ",'updateDt' DATETIME," +
                        " FOREIGN KEY (caseid) REFERENCES CaseEntity(id));" +

                "INSERT INTO TaskEntityNew(text,caseid,status,datetime,updateDt) SELECT text,caseid,status,datetime,update FROM TaskEntity;"+

                "DROP TABLE TaskEntity;" +

                "ALTER TABLE 'TaskEntityNew' RENAME TO 'TaskEntity';" +

                "COMMIT;"
        );
```

But I am getting this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle TaskEntity(EntityCollection.TaskEntity).
                                                                                 Expected:
                                                                                TableInfo{name='TaskEntity', columns={text=Column{name='text', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, updateDt=Column{name='updateDt', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, datetime=Column{name='datetime', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, status=Column{name='status', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, caseid=Column{name='caseid', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='CaseEntity', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[caseid], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_TaskEntity_caseid', unique=false, columns=[caseid]}]}
                                                                                 Found:
                                                                                TableInfo{name='TaskEntity', columns={text=Column{name='text', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, updateDt=Column{name='updateDt', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, datetime=Column{name='datetime', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, status=Column{name='status', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, caseid=Column{name='caseid', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='CaseEntity', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[caseid], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_TaskEntity_caseid', unique=false, columns=[caseid]}]}
```

What I can think of a problem is that my SQL block is not executing and my old table data is trying to match with the old java entity class.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I wish someone would have answered the question instead of editing the title and removing Android from the beginning.

Comment: Can you provide us with the POJO class? I suppose the POJO should be fine based on the error you getting.. It seems to me the migration code was not called.. Have you incremented Database version in the Room annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `execSQL` only executes a single SQL statement:

> the SQL statement to be executed. Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.

so you need to rewrite your code into multiple calls like:

```
database.execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION;");

database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TaskEntityNew('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "'text' TEXT," +
        "'caseid' INTEGER NULL," +
        "'status' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
        "'datetime' DATETIME," +
        ",'updateDt' DATETIME," +
        " FOREIGN KEY (caseid) REFERENCES CaseEntity(id));");

database.execSQL("INSERT INTO TaskEntityNew(text,caseid,status,datetime,updateDt) SELECT text,caseid,status,datetime,update FROM TaskEntity;");

database.execSQL("DROP TABLE TaskEntity;");

database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'TaskEntityNew' RENAME TO 'TaskEntity';");

database.execSQL("COMMIT;");
```

As-is, SQLite is executing "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" then ignoring the rest of your SQL statements.